# Corrupted tables in postgresql: invalid relnatts, attrelid and typrelid

Tags: postgresql, migration, corruption

When trying to upgrade my databases from Postgresql 9.5.4 to 9.6.3, two tables are corrupted.

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.4_1/bin/pg_catcheck -h localhost -p 5434 db_concepts_2
notice: pg_type row has invalid typrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: oid="16441"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="custid" attnum="1"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="firstname" attnum="2"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="lastname" attnum="3"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="dateofbirth" attnum="4"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="telephoneno" attnum="5"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="ctid" attnum="-1"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="xmin" attnum="-3"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="cmin" attnum="-4"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="xmax" attnum="-5"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="cmax" attnum="-6"
notice: pg_attribute row has invalid attrelid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: attrelid="16439" attname="tableoid" attnum="-7"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "10": attribute 5 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16431" relname="purchase_purchid_seq" relkind="S"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "10": attribute 6 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16431" relname="purchase_purchid_seq" relkind="S"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "10": attribute 7 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16431" relname="purchase_purchid_seq" relkind="S"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "10": attribute 8 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16431" relname="purchase_purchid_seq" relkind="S"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "10": attribute 9 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16431" relname="purchase_purchid_seq" relkind="S"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "10": attribute 10 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16431" relname="purchase_purchid_seq" relkind="S"
notice: pg_depend row has invalid refobjid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: classid="1247" objid="16441" objsubid="0" refclassid="1259" refobjid="16439" refobjsubid="0" deptype="i"
notice: pg_depend row has invalid objid "16439": no matching entry in pg_class
row identity: classid="1259" objid="16439" objsubid="0" refclassid="2615" refobjid="2200" refobjsubid="0" deptype="n"
progress: done (20 inconsistencies, 0 warnings, 0 errors)


$ /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.4_1/bin/pg_catcheck -h localhost -p 5434 dataviz
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "3": attribute 1 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16388" relname="pg_toast_16385" relkind="t"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "3": attribute 2 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16388" relname="pg_toast_16385" relkind="t"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "3": attribute 3 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16388" relname="pg_toast_16385" relkind="t"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "2": attribute 1 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16390" relname="pg_toast_16385_index" relkind="i"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "2": attribute 2 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16390" relname="pg_toast_16385_index" relkind="i"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "6": attribute 1 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16385" relname="tesco_items" relkind="r"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "6": attribute 2 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16385" relname="tesco_items" relkind="r"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "6": attribute 3 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16385" relname="tesco_items" relkind="r"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "6": attribute 4 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16385" relname="tesco_items" relkind="r"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "6": attribute 5 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16385" relname="tesco_items" relkind="r"
notice: pg_class row has invalid relnatts "6": attribute 6 does not exist in pg_attribute
row identity: oid="16385" relname="tesco_items" relkind="r"
progress: done (11 inconsistencies, 0 warnings, 0 errors)
```

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Dump and reload. Keep a copy of the old db for forensic analysis/debugging. See also https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption . If pg_dump fails things get interesting...

Comment: Do you know how it got this way?